# Corrupted files when updated on OneDrive

Tags: android, onedrive

I’ve been working on an app that let users open files via the [storage access framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) in Android. If the user opens a file via OneDrive, it will be incorrectly stored when saved if file has become smaller. For instance, if this is the original file content:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Then user the change the file content to this:

```
A
B
!
```

Then it will be stored like this:

```
A
B
!
D
E
```

This happens only if the file is on OneDrive. Local files and files on Google Drive or Dropbox works as expected. This behavior is not only in my app, but also in [OldSchool Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abhishek.oldschooleditor) and [Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.byteexperts.texteditor).

I have created a super simple demo app here: https://github.com/pekspro/CorruptFileDemo It just has an open button, a save button and an edit box. The essential code is this:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> mGetContent;
private Uri OpenFileUri;

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                    try (InputStream in = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri))
                    {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        String text = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
                        binding.editBox.setText(text);

                        OpenFileUri = uri;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

    binding.buttonOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mGetContent.launch(new String[] {"text/*"});
        }
    });

    binding.buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (OpenFileUri == null)
                return;

            try (OutputStream mOutputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(OpenFileUri)) {
                try (PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(mOutputStream)) {
                    String t = binding.editBox.getText().toString();
                    p.println(t);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My guess this is a bug in OneDrive. But is it something I could change to make sure the files are stored correctly?

Comment: .openOutputStream(OpenFileUri, "wt")

Comment: Nice suggestion @blackapps. Unfortunately, it didn't changed anything :(